# Is it possible create OpsGenie incident (not alert) by Java API?

Tags: alerts, opsgenie

I am trying integrate Camunda spring boot app with Opsgenie space of our project. After adding Java SDK as the dependency, it's possible now to create alert to the Opsgenie project. But i need create **incident** (it is the type of alert as [docs](https://support.atlassian.com/opsgenie/docs/what-is-an-incident/) say), but i found only incident [Rest API](https://docs.opsgenie.com/docs/incident-api#create-incident) for this purpose - [Java API](https://docs.opsgenie.com/docs/opsgenie-java-api) creates **only alerts**.

Should i write custom implementation of this API method in Java?
Help, please, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From [doc](https://support.atlassian.com/opsgenie/docs/what-is-an-incident/): incidents can be created manually, or their creation can be automated

> by consolidating Alerts through the use of Incident Rules

Thats why, maybe, Java API creates only alerts

Comment: thanks, i'll try rules.. but why Rest API have such a method?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create incidents. You can use [opsgenie-oas](https://github.com/opsgenie/opsgenie-oas) project and generate the API client code using [open API generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator).